# casting to Dictionary<String, AnyObject> broken after upgrading to Xcode 6 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My app worked fine in Xcode 6 beta 5 but is broken in beta 6. It looks like

```
let jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

In beta 6, jsonDictionary is always nil as the result of "as?" casting. I also tried

```
Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
```

with no luck.

Can anyone provide a workaround? thx!

Edit:
I tried the following:
if casted to NSDictionary, it's not nil (good); 
if casted to Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, it's nil; 
if casted to Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>, it's nil.

Edit:
I changed the original title so it's less misleading. Thx for those who down-voted it in the first place :-)

Comment: We need some more info here, I guarantee `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` didn't just break and always returns `nil` all of the sudden. Perhaps what you're passing it is nil or malformed?

Comment: @ChrisWagner You are right. That class method call is fine. I can print out its result, which is fine - same as what I got in Xcode 6 Beta 5. It's the "as" casting that fails now. The API returns AnyObject?. However it could be casted to Dictionary<String, AnyObject> but now it cannot - so it is nil.

Comment: I'm working with JSON and when passing from beta 5 to beta 6 I didn't find any problem. I am casting to `NSDictionary` though, so maybe it's worth to give it a try

Comment: @Antonio thx for the input. I already knew/tried NSDictionary and it is good, like what you said. Is there any way to still use Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> which Apple says is bridged to NSDictionary automatically?

Comment: This is a long shot, but I had a friend run into some casting problems similar to this but with a different outcome. Deleting the contents of `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` fixed his problems. I too have seen that deleting the derived data between Xcode updates has fixed some very strange issues.

Comment: @GoldThumb have you tried a cascade cast `as? NSDictionary as? [String:AnyObject]`?

Comment: @Antonio just tried(also NSObject:AnyObject), still nil.

Comment: just tried with my code, and `let dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &error) as [String:AnyObject]` returns a valid dict with data in it. What's the difference with yours?

Comment: @ChrisWagner Your suggestion fixes my problem!

Comment: Fascinating! Glad it did work for you. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as answer...

> This is a long shot, but I had a friend run into some casting problems similar to this but with a different outcome. Deleting the contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ fixed his problems. I too have seen that deleting the derived data between Xcode updates has fixed some very strange issues.

Comment: It also fixes weird issues like: system constants like UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification fail to work; compiler complains like "forcedBridgingFromObjectiveC" (might not be the exactly same text).